# NSURLConnection is returning null when XML is expected

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a basecamp account which I'm trying to access via its XML API.

I have created a NSURL Request with proper header fields.

```
    NSURL* projectsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.accountURL stringByAppendingString:@"/projects.xml"]];
    NSMutableURLRequest* projectsRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:projectsUrl];

    [projectsRequest setValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [projectsRequest setValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
```

I create a connection and start it.

```
    NSURLConnection* connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:projectsRequest delegate:self];
    [connection start];
    [connection autorelease];
```

Basecamp uses HTTP basic authentication. So I use a NSCredential object to handle it as below.

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge*)authenticationChallenge
{


    if ([authenticationChallenge previousFailureCount] <=2 ) {
        NSURLCredential* basecampCredentials;
        basecampCredentials = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:[self username] 
                                                         password:[self password]
                                                      persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];
        [[authenticationChallenge sender] useCredential:basecampCredentials forAuthenticationChallenge:authenticationChallenge];
    }else {
        [[authenticationChallenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:authenticationChallenge];

    }

}
```

And when I receive data from connection i handle it with these delegates.

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [[self responseData] appendData: data];
    NSLog(@"I received %@", [self responseData]);

}


-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection
{
    NSLog(@"I FINALLY received %@", [self responseData]);

    NSXMLParser* parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:[self responseData]];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    BOOL success = [parser parse];
    if (success) {
        NSLog(@"XML parse success");
    }else {
        NSLog(@"XML parse ERROR");
    }

    [parser autorelease];

}
```

The problem is even after using right urls, authentication credentials and header fields I get `null` data in `responseData` whereas when I try to access the same url with `curl` I get proper xml response from the basecamp server. I'm new to objective C. Please explain and tell me what else should I set to get this right.

Comment: Did you initiate the `responseData` ?

Comment: ya, initializing the responseData worked. thanks a lot

Comment: wel. my friend, if you feel that my comment helped you, please vote :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before starting connection (`[connection start];`) you should initialise property `responseData`, for example, `self.responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];`.

In method `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response` you should set the length of that data to zero : `[self.responseData setLength:0];`

Comment: initing the responseData worked. Further, why should i set its length to zero?

Comment: Because this method could be called several times. You need to store data only after last call.

Comment: @Anand: Further to Nekto's comment, for things like URL redirects where you will get multiple `didReceiveResponse:` calls, there may be some data received, but this should be discarded when the final HTTP response is received as this previous data is not actually part of the final page that is loaded.

Comment: Thanks @darvids0n! That's what i mean

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you set `[self responseData]`?

Comment: yeah, i append it with this  code   [[self responseData] appendData: data];  in didReceiveData method

Comment: Can you paste the code where you initalise it?

eg, [self setResponseData:[NSMutableData data]]

Answer (score 0):

Try the same URL with an [`ASIHTTPRequest`](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) and see if it works.

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest is awesome. Just checked it out. Some things are really made easy.